# Querying AD for finding all groups of a user - Missing one group

Tags: c#, .net, search, active-directory

I've the following code to query AD using `DirectorySearcher` to get all the AD groups for a user.

```
        List<string> Groups = new List<string>();

        //initialize the directory entry object 
        DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry(ldapPath);

        //directory searcher
        DirectorySearcher dirSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry);

        //enter the filter
        dirSearcher.Filter = string.Format("(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName={0}))", username);

        //get the member of properties for the search result
        dirSearcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
        int propCount;
        SearchResult dirSearchResults = dirSearcher.FindOne();
        propCount = dirSearchResults.Properties["memberOf"].Count;
        string dn;
        int equalsIndex;
        int commaIndex;
        for (int i = 0; i <= propCount - 1; i++)
        {
            dn = dirSearchResults.Properties["memberOf"][i].ToString();

            equalsIndex = dn.IndexOf("=", 1);
            commaIndex = dn.IndexOf(",", 1);
            if (equalsIndex == -1)
            {
                return null;
            }
            if (!Groups.Contains(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1)))
            {
                Groups.Add(dn.Substring((equalsIndex + 1), (commaIndex - equalsIndex) - 1));
            }
        }

        return Groups;
```

But when i check the 'memberof' tab in AD for a user I've one additional group 'Domain Users' which I'm not getting through this code.

Any ideas? Why I'm not getting 'Domain Users' in the 'memberof' collection?

Comment: Could be based on the server you are hitting's config and it's role/function, see the memberOf portion of this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms677943

Comment: Okie. I learnt from here - http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30375857/directory-searcher-not-returning-all-groups.aspx that memberOf wont return Primary Groups of a user. But I can get the primaryGroupID which gives the RID(?) of the group using which I need to get the AD group. Any ideas how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Groups can be members of other groups. Maybe your users are not direct members, but only indirect members?

I do iterate all groups for child groups, too, when retrieving the groups on an AD.

Be warned that you may get endless recursion, since groups can (indirectly) contain each other. I had a hard time finding this out :-( Now I remember each processed group in a "global" list to only process it once to avoid this).

I've written a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/ZetaEnterpriseLibrary.aspx) with some general purpose libraries, that contains AD classes, too. (See the classes in the "`/Tools/DirectoryServices/`" sub folder in the downloaded ZIP file).

Comment: So how can I find it recursively using DirectorySearcher?

Comment: I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: Okie. I've recursive found the parent groups. But still two groups (or folders?) 'Domain Users' is not coming in the list. But if I check the 'memberOf' tab it is there. Domain users is a builtin group right? Am I missing something here?

Comment: What helped me when dealing with "AD stuff" is the LDAP Browser from Softerra. See http://www.ldapbrowser.com/download.htm - Be sure to use the version 2.6 which is free and was still sufficient for my needs. With the help of the Softerra browser, I could see much more details of groups and userers, etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but for anyone else searching, the reason that the memberof attribute was missing "Domain Users" is because that was the AD object's PRIMARY GROUP. To find a user's primary group, you need to:

1. Get the user's primaryGroupID attribute, which is the unique serial ID of the group object within the domain
2. Construct the group's objectSID (take the user object's objectSID and replace the last digit group with the primaryGroupID)
3. Get the group based on the constructed SID